# Post messages from various views/controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am still a rookie in Rails and when I start inventing things I know I am not doing it the Rails way ;)

How do you solve the following problem without repeating yourself and followint the Rails convention?

Users in my app can send messages to each other. They can do it when viewing a listing that someone is selling in a form found under the listing show view: **/listing/X**

But also they can send messages to each other once the listing has been bought in a form found on e.g:
**/admin/payments/Y**

I solved this problem by posting the forms to **Listing** and **Payment** controllers respectively to a action **messaging**. To have a non CRUD action I added member in routes.rb:

```
  resources :listings, :payments do
    member do
      post 'messaging'
    end
  end
```

This way both controllers have actions to which I can POST my message form and then in messaging method I create hte message using Message.new etc.

Works like  a charm, but I was thinking there has to be a better way such as POSTing both forms to a separate `MessagesCottroller::create` method?

Also, maybe I should extract messaging logic into a concern and include it in `ListingsController`, `PaymentsController` or any other controller that needs to "process" new messages since it's not DRY this way?

One more thing... All messages `belongs_to` conversation so I created `ConversationsController` that serves as an inbox of all conversations  for each user where I use only the index and show actions to list all conversations and to show each conversation respectively. 
When a user opens **/conversation/X** he sees all messages and a form to reply. As you can see user is not posting a conversation, but a message.

So taking into account that a message belongs_to conversation, message is posted through forms found in listing/x, payment/Y or conversation/X should I be solving this by:

- adding MessagesController and posting each form directly to it and then redirecting bak to the view s listing/x, payment/y or conversation/z?
- Keeping message creation in each controller separately and maybe using concern to DRY it a little bit?

Thank you so much

Comment: You've got the solution there already. Create a MessagesController, post to that, create the message, then redirect back to wherever you need to be. You shouldn't be creating messages in multiple places.

Comment: I ended up doing just that because I thought about pure RESTful where creating of a message has to be behind POST to URI /messages and not listings/messages or payments/messages... :) thanks for the confirmation!